# The call to BuildHttpClientBase.GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync doesn't return work items created by users with stakeholder access

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) to obtain the list of work items that were associated with some builds. For that purpose I'm using the following code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;

public async Task<IEnumerable<ResourceRef>> GetBuildWorkItems(string vstsUrl, string teamProjectName, int buildId, string pat)
{
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
    using (var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>())
    {
        var workItems = await buildClient.GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync(teamProjectName, buildId);                
        return workItems;
    }
}
```

This works fine except when the work items are created by a user with stakeholder access level. These work items in particular aren't returned by the `GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync` method.

Is this by design? Is there something I can configure in the VSTS Admin settings regarding the stakeholder users so that this doesn't happen?

Just for clarification, I'm using TFVC instead of Git on my team project. I don't know if that is relevant for this question.

Comment: What's the result if you link the build to two work items, one created by Stakeholder user and another one created by Basic user and get the work items via the code?

Answer (score 1):

Tried the `GetBuildWorkItemsRefsAsync` method, and didn't figure out the problem.

However you can simply use the REST API to get the list of work items that were associated with a specific build:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version=4.1
```

See [Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.

PowerShell for example:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com",
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$BuildID = "283",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$WITbaseUrl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/builds/$($BuildID)/workitems"

#Response           
$WITresponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WITbaseUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value

$WITrequests = @()

foreach($WITrequest in $WITresponse){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WorkitemID" = $WITrequest.id
          "WorkitemURL" = $WITrequest.url
        } 

    $WITrequests += $customObject       
}

$WITrequests | Select `
               WorkitemID,
               WorkitemURL
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Instead of using PoweShell, I used Postman to call the REST API. The result was the same. Basically I made two tests: one with a buildId that has linked work items that were created by a user with stakeholder access level; and a second test with a buildId that as linked work items created by a user with Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription access level. The first test returned an empty list of work items (this was the returned json: {"count": 0, "value": []}) while the second test returned the correct linked work items. Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: @DuarteSilva Which user did you use to run the REST API? Stakeholder users don't have the permission to view builds, this maybe the root cause.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear about that point. I created a personal access token associated with my user (which has Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription access level) and have been using that PAT in every test that I've described. The authorized scopes for that PAT are Build(read) and Work items (full). Do I need more scopes in this case?

Comment: @DuarteSilva No more else, the scopes should be OK. But I cannot reproduce the issue on my side. I can see all the associated work items even they were created by the Stakeholder users. Can you see the associated work items from the build summary page?

Comment: yes I can see the associated work items on the build summary page. I'm beginning to wonder if I'm doing something completely dumb on my side...

Comment: @DuarteSilva What about changing your account which to view the work items to Basic access level?

Comment: sorry for not responding to your question in a timely manner. I finally figured out the source of the problem. The fact that a stakeholder user was creating the work items in my scenario, was a mere coincidence. The problem lies with the workspace mappings. If I use pipeline variables in the mappings (i.e.: $\TeamProject\$(branch)\), the problem that I described appears. I decided to open a support request directly with Microsoft explaining the scenario. The support request is still open and they are investigating the issue. Thank you for your help.